# Two compatible topologically equivalent norms on a module over a non-archimedean field but not metrically equivalent?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

The direct question is:

> Let $F$ be a field, with the trivial norm, that is, $|x|=\begin{cases}1&x\ne0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$. Let $M$ be a free module over $F$ with basis $\left\{x_i\mid i=1,2,\cdots\right\}$. Define two norms $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ by $$|\sum_ia_ix_i|_j=\sup_i|a_i|\cdot|x_i|_j=\sup_{a_i\ne0}|x_i|_j,$$
>   where $|x_i|_1=i$ and $|x_i|_2=i^2$. Then are these two norms metrically inequivalent but topologically equivalent?

I think they are metrically inequivalent because there is no constant $c>0$ such that $i^2<c\cdot i,\,\forall i=1,2\cdots$. And I think they are topologically equivalent because they both generate the discrete topology (the point $0$ is open in both topologies).

---

Why ask this?

In the book *p-adic Differential Equations* by **Kiran.S.Kedlaya** one finds the exercise I.1.(4):

> Let $M$ be a module over a non-archimedean field $F$. Prove that any two norms compatible with $F$ are topologically equivalent if and only if they are metrically equivalent.

And I think the above paragraph provides a counter-example to this exercise. Per chance the book is missing the condition the the norm on the filed should not be trivial (in which case I figured out how to prove it).

---

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, books about p-adic analysis state at the beginning that they will work with non-trivial valuations on the field to avoid a number of pathologies like the one you mention.  Nice counter-example by the way.

Comment: @Chilote But in the example 1.4.1 in the book, one finds the definition of the trivial norm, and the statement that The trivial case is always allowed, unless explicitly excluded. This is why I think the exercise misses some hypothesis. Thanks for the reply still. :)

Comment: I'm sure that if you e-mail your valid question to the author of the book you will get an answer. Let us know how did it go!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will surely find time to email later.